# how to set a default value in codeigniter?

Tags: php, html, mysql, codeigniter

is there any sugestion to store default value that is posted to database from form html?
my aplication is using mysql as the rdmbs and codeigniter for backend process.

right now, i just using html method at the submit form.

`<input type="hidden" id="" name="" value="">`

at the html page and set the value there.
but the value is visible when you open the source code in any other browser.
is there any method to store value that is not visible from user in codeigniter?

Comment: Where does the form go when it's submitted? What does that code look like?

Comment: Where do you want to store the default value? At your database, to use when no value is passed or at front end to access even after the page is refreshed

Comment: i dont mind, anywhere that user can't see

Comment: Not really - if you want to keep something secret from the client, the only way is to not send it to them in the first place (keep it on the server).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your form is posting the data on the same method wherefrom it is rendered then the best approach is that; keep the value in the method itself and use it after form submit.

```
public function edit() { 
     $id = 12;
     if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
         $dataComm    = array(
                            'id'  => $id
                            'name'       => $this->input->post('name') 
                            );
                            $result_comm = $this->Common_model->insert_data('cw_franchise_commission', $dataComm);
     }
     $this->data['title'] = "Edit User";
     $this->load->view('edit', $this->data);
 }
```

And if your form action is another method then you can encode the value and decode it after form submission.

**To Encode**

```
bin2hex(base64_encode($id))
```

**To Decode**

```
base64_decode(hex2bin($this->input->post('id')));
```

One more thing if you are using hidden inputs then you should name it something confusing not clear at all. Otherwise, anyone can understand the purpose of the field.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such a way but you can keep it in encoding format using

base64_encode()

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<php echo base64_encode('1231231231'.$id); ?>">
```

"1231231231" just for additional security which will preprend with the id

cut "1231231231" in controller like below to get the id

```
    function abc() {
    if (isset($_POST['id']) && !empty($_POST['id'])) {
        $id = substr(base64_decode($_GET['id']), 10); // to remive extra string
        if (!empty($id)) {
            // you  get id here
        } else {
            //if someone attempt to tamper with the id then it will retrive blank
        }
    } else {
        //redirect or show error
    }
}
```